# Async callback doesn't get called

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a frustrating problem.
I am trying to extract a function that is used in many classes.
Doing this gives me problems with the 'done'-callback.
Here is my code:

I have extracted the function and added it to util.js:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;
var util = exports = module.exports = {};

chai.use(require('chai-http'));
chai.use(require('chai-string'));

util.testAsyncCalls = function testAsyncCalls(urlArray, urlSuffix, result, callback) {
    async.each(urlArray, function (url, callback) {
        chai.request(url)
            .get(urlSuffix)
            .then(function (res) {
                expect(res).to.have.status(200);
                expect(res.body.totalStatus, res.body.summary).to.equalIgnoreCase(result);
                callback();
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                callback(err);
            });
    });
};
```

Then, in the test itself, I call the function like below:

```
 var config = require(process.env.CONFIG || '../env.json'),
   util = require('../util.js');
    describe('App', function () {
        it('Is /home ok ?', function(done) {
            util.testAsyncCalls(config.url.applications, '/home/info', 'SUCCESS', done);
        })
    });
```

Running the test via mocha gives me the following error:

```
Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

When I perform a normal get on the url, I get a valid response so I assume the callback is the problem.
Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance.
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call your "global" callback at the end of the each, look at the [each signature](https://github.com/caolan/async#each)

```
util.testAsyncCalls = function testAsyncCalls(urlArray, urlSuffix, result, callback) {
    async.each(urlArray, function (url, next) {
        chai.request(url)
        .get(urlSuffix)
        .then(function (res) {
            expect(res).to.have.status(200);
            expect(res.body.totalStatus, res.body.summary).to.equalIgnoreCase(result);
            next();
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            next(err);
        });
    }, callback);
};
```

As a good practice, don't use the same name for callback in sub scopes, use 'next' for example in your each instead of 'callback'.

Comment: It works, thank you very much. I was confused because I thought that the superMethod received the callback from the .then() or .catch() method. Didn't know it had to be called after the each.